# QtQuick2: Handle onWheel event inside of a ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have to put component X inside of a ScrollView. Component X has to handle mouse wheel event, but ScrollView handles it. So, following example (simplified) doesn't work.

How to let Rectangle's mouse area handle OnWheel event?

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ScrollView {
        height: 100
        width: 100

        ColumnLayout{
            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                width: 50
                height: 50
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onWheel: {
                        console.log("onWheel"); // it doesn't work
                    }
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("onClicked"); // it works
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a way to solve it, but I can't properly explain it. :(

[This document](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html) illustrates the concept of `visual parent` and `object parent`, but it dosen't tell how they affect the event propagation.

Hope someone would give a clear explaination.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ScrollView {
        id: scroll   // add an id
        height: 100
        width: 100

        ColumnLayout{
            Rectangle {
                id: rect   // add an id
                color: "red"
                width: 50
                height: 50
                MouseArea {
                    parent: scroll      // specify the `visual parent`
                    anchors.fill: rect       // fill `object parent` 
                    onWheel: {
                        console.log("onWheel"); // now it works
                    }
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("onClicked"); // it works
                    }
                }
            }
            Repeater {
                model: 30
                Text{ text: index }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response -- I'll try it as soon as possible.

Comment: there is should be `wheel.accepted = false` in `onWheel` handler because handling `onWheel` breaks `ScrollView` behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This as actually a bug in Qt:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38083

This is being resolved in:

- https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,82572
- https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,82576